# How to get data via bluetooth from another device to iphone?

Tags: iphone

In my application i want to get the data from a measuring device using bluetooth and update the iphone GUI accordingly.How could i do this communication using bluetooth.Is it supports all bluetooth profile.
Pls help me as i'm new iphone programmin.